# How to solve in Knex.js ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I had built a query in Knex.js to insert records to the DB

```js
upsert(input) {
    if (isEmpty(input)) return Promise.resolve(0);

    return this.tx(tableName)
      .insert(input.map(prepareInput))
      .onConflict([columns.candidateId, columns.startAt])
      .merge()
      .returning()
      .then(({ rowCount }) => rowCount);
  }
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
```

I need to insert data and merge it with the existing one and not sure how should I edit this query to avoid the error

Comment: There is basically nothing you can do with the query. This error occurs, as described, when a second conflict occurs *for the same value*. You must remove that and any subsequent value from the input data, before submitting to Postgres. Well perhaps you can build a CTE which gets distinct values on the key before Update/Insert.

Comment: So I need to build a raw SQL to make that in this case as KnexJS would not help at all